# Laravel 5.8: Pagination Does Not Seem To Be Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and in this project I have added this pagination:

```
public function index()
    {
        $magazines = Magazine::query()->paginate(100);
        return view('admin.magazines.magazines.index', compact('magazines'));
    }
```

Then at the view, I added this after the `</table>` tag:

`{!! $magazines->appends(request()->query())->render() !!}`

But I don't see any pagination on page!

So how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append query string in controller like below

```
public function index()
{
   $magazines = Magazine::query()->paginate(100)->appends(request()->all());
   return view('admin.magazines.magazines.index', compact('magazines'));
}
```

and in view

```
{!! $magazines->links() !!}
```